# The image is not rendering while running the jar file

Tags: java, geotools

I have very strange problem with rendering the world map as image with geotools when I run my jar file. At the same time, when I compiling my project inside of the NetBeans IDE everything is Ok.
What might be wrong?

Here is full stack trace of the Exception I've got

```
D:\test>java -jar myrunnablejar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Sun Microsystems, Inc.
1.1
Java Advanced Imaging Image I/O Tools

INFO: Begin of the image rendering
imageBounds
X: 0.0 Y: 0.0 width: 3000.0 height: 1447.0
mapBounds
Max X: 180.0 Min X: -180.0 Max Y: 83.62359619140625 Min Y: -90.0
ш■ы 22, 2019 12:42:42 PM org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer fireErrorE
vent
SEVERE: Invalid measure '1.0', was expecting a number, eventually followed by px
, m or ft
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid measure '1.0', was expecting a numbe
r, eventually followed by px, m or ft
        at org.geotools.styling.visitor.Measure.processLiteralExpression(Measure
.java:118)
        at org.geotools.styling.visitor.Measure.processLiteralExpression(Measure
.java:99)
        at org.geotools.styling.visitor.Measure.<init>(Measure.java:62)
        at org.geotools.styling.visitor.UomRescaleStyleVisitor.rescale(UomRescal
eStyleVisitor.java:92)
        at org.geotools.styling.visitor.UomRescaleStyleVisitor.rescaleStroke(Uom
RescaleStyleVisitor.java:141)
        at org.geotools.styling.visitor.UomRescaleStyleVisitor.visit(UomRescaleS
tyleVisitor.java:201)
        at org.geotools.styling.PolygonSymbolizerImpl.accept(PolygonSymbolizerIm
pl.java:130)
        at org.geotools.styling.visitor.DuplicatingStyleVisitor.copy(Duplicating
StyleVisitor.java:508)
        at org.geotools.styling.visitor.DuplicatingStyleVisitor.visit(Duplicatin
gStyleVisitor.java:271)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.rescaleFeatureTypeStyle(
StreamingRenderer.java:2555)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.applyUnitRescale(Streami
ngRenderer.java:2408)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.createLiteFeatureTypeSty
les(StreamingRenderer.java:1966)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(Streaming
Renderer.java:2141)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.
java:892)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.
java:625)
        at wind.maps.crs.WorldMap.saveImage(WorldMap.java:167)
        at wind.maps.crs.WorldMap.display(WorldMap.java:214)
        at wind.maps.main.Main.main(Main.java:109)

ш■ы 22, 2019 12:42:47 PM wind.maps.crs.WorldMap saveImage
INFO: End of the image rendering
ш■ы 22, 2019 12:42:55 PM org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer fireErrorE
vent
SEVERE: Invalid measure '1.0', was expecting a number, eventually followed by px
, m or ft
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid measure '1.0', was expecting a numbe
r, eventually followed by px, m or ft
        at org.geotools.styling.visitor.Measure.processLiteralExpression(Measure
.java:118)
        at org.geotools.styling.visitor.Measure.processLiteralExpression(Measure
.java:99)
        at org.geotools.styling.visitor.Measure.<init>(Measure.java:62)
        at org.geotools.styling.visitor.UomRescaleStyleVisitor.rescale(UomRescal
eStyleVisitor.java:92)
        at org.geotools.styling.visitor.UomRescaleStyleVisitor.rescaleStroke(Uom
RescaleStyleVisitor.java:141)
        at org.geotools.styling.visitor.UomRescaleStyleVisitor.visit(UomRescaleS
tyleVisitor.java:201)
        at org.geotools.styling.PolygonSymbolizerImpl.accept(PolygonSymbolizerIm
pl.java:130)
        at org.geotools.styling.visitor.DuplicatingStyleVisitor.copy(Duplicating
StyleVisitor.java:508)
        at org.geotools.styling.visitor.DuplicatingStyleVisitor.visit(Duplicatin
gStyleVisitor.java:271)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.rescaleFeatureTypeStyle(
StreamingRenderer.java:2555)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.applyUnitRescale(Streami
ngRenderer.java:2408)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.createLiteFeatureTypeSty
les(StreamingRenderer.java:1966)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(Streaming
Renderer.java:2141)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.
java:892)
        at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:101)
        at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:38)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my code:

```
public class WorldMap {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(WorldMap.class.getName()); 
final static String INPUT = "./shape/world.shp";
final static String OUTPUT = "./MAPS/";

private File shapeFile;
private FileDataStoreFactorySpi factory;
private FileDataStore fileDataStore;
private CoordinateReferenceSystem crs;
private SimpleFeatureSource featureSource;
private final Style style;
private final MapContent map;
private final GeometryFactory geometryFactory; 
private final MathTransformFactory mtFactory;
private final CRSFactory crsFactory;

public WorldMap() throws IOException {
    this.factory = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory();
    this.shapeFile = new File(INPUT);        
    this.fileDataStore = (FileDataStore) getDataStore();
    this.featureSource = fileDataStore.getFeatureSource();
    this.style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
    this.map = new MapContent();
    this.geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory( null );
    this.mtFactory = ReferencingFactoryFinder.getMathTransformFactory(null);
    this.crsFactory = ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSFactory(null);        
}

private DataStore getDataStore(){
    DataStore dataStore = null;
    try {
        Map<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
        params.put(ShapefileDataStoreFactory.URLP.key, URLs.fileToUrl(shapeFile));
        dataStore = factory.createDataStore(params);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WorldMap.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return dataStore;
}

public void saveImage(final MapContent map, final String file, int imageWidth) {

    try {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Begin of the image rendering");

        GTRenderer renderer = new StreamingRenderer();
        renderer.setMapContent(map);

        Rectangle imageBounds = null;
        ReferencedEnvelope mapBounds = null;

        mapBounds = map.getViewport().getBounds();
        double heightToWidth = mapBounds.getSpan(1) / mapBounds.getSpan(0);
        imageBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, imageWidth, (int) Math.round(imageWidth * heightToWidth));

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage((int)imageBounds.getWidth(), (int)imageBounds.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D gr = image.createGraphics();

        gr.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
        gr.fill(imageBounds);

        System.out.println("imageBounds");
        System.out.println("X: " + imageBounds.getBounds().getX() + " Y: " + imageBounds.getBounds().getY() + " width: " + imageBounds.getWidth() + " height: " + imageBounds.getHeight());

        System.out.println("mapBounds");
        System.out.println("Max X: " + mapBounds.getMaxX() + " Min X: " + mapBounds.getMinX() + " Max Y: " + mapBounds.getMaxY() + " Min Y: " + mapBounds.getMinY());

        renderer.paint(gr, imageBounds, mapBounds);
        File fileToSave = new File(file);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", fileToSave);

        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "End of the image rendering");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WorldMap.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

public void display(){        
    map.addLayer(new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style));  
    saveImage(map, OUTPUT + "image.png", 800);
    addJMapFrame();
}  

public void addJMapFrame(){
    JMapFrame mapFrame = new JMapFrame(map);
    mapFrame.enableToolBar(true);
    mapFrame.enableStatusBar(true);

    JToolBar toolbar = mapFrame.getToolBar();
    toolbar.addSeparator();

    mapFrame.setSize(2156, 1728);
    mapFrame.setVisible(true);        
}

class ValidateGeometryAction extends SafeAction {
    ValidateGeometryAction() {
        super("Validate geometry");
        putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Check each geometry");
    }

    @Override
    public void action(java.awt.event.ActionEvent ae) throws Throwable {
        int numInvalid = validateFeatureGeometry(null);
        String msg;
        if (numInvalid == 0) {
            msg = "All feature geometries are valid";
        } else {
            msg = "Invalid geometries: " + numInvalid;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, "Geometry results", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}

private int validateFeatureGeometry(ProgressListener progress) throws Exception {
    final SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = featureSource.getFeatures();
    class ValidationVisitor implements FeatureVisitor {
        public int numInvalidGeometries = 0;
        @Override
        public void visit(Feature f) {
            SimpleFeature feature = (SimpleFeature) f;
            Geometry geom = (Geometry) feature.getDefaultGeometry();
            if (geom != null && !geom.isValid()) {
                numInvalidGeometries++;
                System.out.println("Invalid Geoemtry: " + feature.getID());
            }
        }
    }
    ValidationVisitor visitor = new ValidationVisitor();
    featureCollection.accepts(visitor, progress);
    return visitor.numInvalidGeometries;
}

class ExportShapefileAction extends SafeAction {
    ExportShapefileAction() {
        super("Export...");
        putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Export using current crs");
    }

    @Override
    public void action(java.awt.event.ActionEvent ae) throws Throwable {
        exportToShapefile();
    }
}

private void exportToShapefile() throws Exception {
    SimpleFeatureType schema = featureSource.getSchema();
    JFileDataStoreChooser chooser = new JFileDataStoreChooser("shp");
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Save reprojected shapefile");
    chooser.setSaveFile(shapeFile);
    int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (returnVal != JFileDataStoreChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        return;
    }
    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    if (file.equals(shapeFile)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot replace " + file);
        return;
    }

    CoordinateReferenceSystem dataCRS = schema.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
    CoordinateReferenceSystem worldCRS = map.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
    boolean lenient = true; 
    MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(dataCRS, worldCRS, lenient);

    SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = featureSource.getFeatures();

    DataStoreFactorySpi factory = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory();
    Map<String, Serializable> create = new HashMap<>();
    create.put("url", file.toURI().toURL());
    create.put("create spatial index", Boolean.TRUE);
    DataStore dataStore = factory.createNewDataStore(create);
    SimpleFeatureType featureType = SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder.retype(schema, worldCRS);
    dataStore.createSchema(featureType);

    String createdName = dataStore.getTypeNames()[0];

    Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("Reproject");
    try (FeatureWriter<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> writer =
                    dataStore.getFeatureWriterAppend(createdName, transaction);
            SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = featureCollection.features()) {
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            SimpleFeature feature = iterator.next();
            SimpleFeature copy = writer.next();
            copy.setAttributes(feature.getAttributes());

            Geometry geometry = (Geometry) feature.getDefaultGeometry();
            Geometry geometry2 = JTS.transform(geometry, transform);

            copy.setDefaultGeometry(geometry2);
            writer.write();
        }
        transaction.commit();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Export to shapefile complete");
    } catch (Exception problem) {
        transaction.rollback();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Export to shapefile failed");
    } finally {
        transaction.close();
    }
}


class ValidateGeometryAction2 extends SafeAction {
    ValidateGeometryAction2() {
        super("Validate geometry");
        putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Check each geometry");
    }

    @Override
    public void action(java.awt.event.ActionEvent ae) throws Throwable {
        SwingWorker worker =
                new SwingWorker<String, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        final JProgressWindow progress = new JProgressWindow(null);
                        progress.setTitle("Validating feature geometry");

                        int numInvalid = validateFeatureGeometry(progress);
                        if (numInvalid == 0) {
                            return "All feature geometries are valid";
                        } else {
                            return "Invalid geometries: " + numInvalid;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void done() {
                        try {
                            Object result = get();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                                    null,
                                    result,
                                    "Geometry results",
                                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        } catch (HeadlessException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException ignore) {
                        }
                    }
                };
        worker.execute();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If your program works in your IDE but not when compiled into a jar, then you are assembling the jar badly. You first need to make sure all the GeoTools modules you are using (gt-main, gt-referencing, gt-shape, gt-rendering etc) are included in the jar.

Also, you have to make sure you handle the `META-INF/services` directory contents are correctly combined rather than just the last jar added overwriting the contents of the previous ones.

See the [GeoTools FAQ](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/build/faq.html?highlight=shade#how-do-i-create-an-executable-jar-for-my-geotools-app) to see a full example of using the [Maven Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) to handle this.

Comment: Which exactly files do I need to copy into the jar META-INF/services dir? I use world .shp, .sld attributes file, and .csv data files, which are created dynamically so I can't put them inside of the .jar. Do you mean that I should copy .shp file into the META-INF?

Comment: No, see my updated answer